# Give specific name to NetworkService in IIS for debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis

I have multiple websites I am working on at any given time. One problem that I run into is that a lot of these websites are using the `NetworkService` identity. As such, when I open the `Attach to Process` dialog in visual studio, it can be difficult to select the correct `w3wp.exe` process for the website I am currently working on.

Without changing the identity from a `NetworkService` is there any way to give each w3wp its own "unique" name that is shown in the `Attach to Process` dialog in visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use something like [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) to view the command line of the various w3wp.exe processes, you can see the application pool name (`-ap` parameter), then you have the Process ID which you also see in Visual Studio.

[image]

Newer versions of Task Manager also allow you to see the full command line under `Details`, so you don't need any additional tools.